# how can i display my promise datas inside of a variable?

Tags: javascript, axios, es6-promise

I want to store an object returned from a promise inside a variable.

I used `then` and `catch` to get the object but when I log the result of my object getting `undefined`.

Here is my code **:**

```js
    let allStudents;
    const getStudents = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await Axios.get('/api/v1/student/')
            return response
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
    
    let gsk = getStudents().then((res) => {
        allStudents = res.data
        return allStudents
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
    
    console.log(allStudents)
```

Comment: You said you are using vuejs with composition api but your above code is pure js. Please try to find the exact problem what you are looking for so that other can give you solution as soon ass possible.

Comment: I suggest you remove reference to Vuejs from the question and rework the title to be along the lines of "data obtained from promise is undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `.then()` on a promise, your callback is not going to be called right away. In particular, the function calling `.then()` will continue to execute, such that lines that come later in the function will be executed *before* your callback.

In your example, the assignment to `allStudents` does not happen until the callback executes, and this is not going to happen until after you have already tried to print out the value with `console.log(allStudents)`.

```
let gsk = getStudents().then((res) => {
  // this code not executed until getStudents() complete
  allStudents= res.data
  return  allStudents
})

// this code is executed before getStudents() completes
console.log(allStudents)
```

In order to wait for the promise to resolve before continuing your execution, you could use `await` instead:

```
let res = await getStudents(); // do not continue until getStudents() completes
allStudents = res.data;
console.log(allStudents);
```